# I18next reload always set default page title language for first seconds

Tags: multilingual, i18next

[I'm trying to add multi-languages for my app but get some troubles. When I try to reload a page, the page title is always the default language. Here is my i18n init. Very appreciate your help, thank you!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOPge.png)

[My i18next init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOPge.png)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and did a workaround to solve this as there is not a lot of help about this in the official documentation.
Here is what I did.
In i18n initilization added

```
lng: localStorage.getItem("i18nextLng") || "tr",
fallbackLng: localStorage.getItem("i18nextLng") || "tr",
```

On language change set lang key in local storage like

```
localStorage.setItem("i18nextLng", langKey);
```

This solved all the edge cases for me. I hope this will help.

Comment: With using the languageDetector this should not be necessary. Just make sure the lng option is NOT set.

Comment: With languageDetector, it will always go for default language even if the user selects one and reload. In other words, the language detector checks and sets with each reload so in some edge cases it will fail I guess.

Comment: never experienced this in my setups, a reproducible example would help to analyze your problem

Comment: Yeah Sure @adrai